# UISearchBar Layout Issues (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, layout, uisearchbar

I'm making what should be a simple change to an app to add a `UISearchBar` component, but am getting some fairly strange layout quirks in the UI.  It's perhaps easier to illustrate using pictures.

Here's what the component looks like when it doesn't have focus:

[image: UISearchBar default]

Note that the icon and the placeholder text are too far over, and the placeholder text is too far up.  And here's what happens when I tap on the field:

[image]

The icon is now in the correct place, but the placeholder text is now too far to the left and overlapping with the icon.  What gives?

When the field loses focus, it reverts to its original layout.  Unless I type some text into it first, in which case it retains the second layout.

The code I'm using to set up the `UISearchBar` isn't doing anything special:

```
    UIView* containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    containerView.backgroundColor = UI_COLOR_NAV_TITLEBAR;

    searchField = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, containerView.frame.size.width - 40, 44)];
    searchField.placeholder = @"search all items";
    searchField.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

    searchField.showsBookmarkButton = NO;
    searchField.showsCancelButton = NO;
    searchField.showsScopeBar = NO;
    searchField.showsSearchResultsButton = NO;

    UITextField* textSearchField = [searchField valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    searchField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textSearchField.textColor = UI_COLOR_NAV_TEXT;

    searchField.delegate = self;
    [containerView addSubview:searchField];

    //...
```

I want the `UISearchBar` to always appear as in the second example, except obviously without the text field overlapping with the icon.  Is there a simple solution to this issue that I've overlooked?

Comment: did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code for searchField..

```
[searchField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
[searchField setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
[searchField setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchicon.png"]];
```

Last is to show icon at left side, use image for that.

Comment: That helps with the icon issue, but doesn't stop the text field from moving around on focus/unfocus.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to remove layer animations from uisearchbar. It will be easy if you try creating custom search bar.